# TypeError: Worker is not a constructor

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Trying to setup a WebWorker inside Lightning App based on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116064/using-webworkers-in-lightning-component-client-controller).

```
Initialise worker    <ui:button press="{!c.doWork}"/>

doWork : function(component, event, helper) {
        var wv = new Worker("/resource/webworker");
        wv.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log('Message received from worker: ' + e.data);
        };

        wv.postMessage (1000000000);
    }
```

Unfortunately getting this error. Is this the case where framework banishes useful browser feature? :)

```
Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$Demo$controller$doWork [TypeError: Worker is not a constructor]
Failing descriptor: {c$Demo$controller$doWork}.
Please try again.
```

Comment: Do you have `Locker Service` enabled? Doug seemed pretty clear they would have a hard time supporting it at least in the Summer '16 release.

Comment: Yes that was the case. Wish they'd throw security exception instead of this :) So what are the security risks that Workers introduce? As far as I am concerned, you load code from static resource, just as you'd do using ltng:require.

Comment: Not sure if you can get disclosure on that front. It sounds like something they want to support, but have not been able to get enough time to work on.

Comment: OWASP does mention obvious issues that you get from untrusted scripts, but in this case you load scripts internally. I hope they do not introduce another proxy framework to handle messaging like they are trying to with Local Storage. Unless there is a way for Worker to disregard CORS, I don't see a problem. I hope I am wrong though.